# Does anybody calculate the gravitational pull efect of the photons spreading anywhere from the stars on the rest of cosmic objects?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, space-expansion

Since the big bang an incredible huge ammount of radiation have been spreading from the stars to everywhere and it must exerts a considerable gravitational pull to the rest of the stars. I haven't find any article talking about it. Could somebody explain or tell where is the answer?

Comment: There's gotta be less energy from stars then from the cosmic background radiation i think.  Either way there is a complicating factor in that all photons will lose energy due to the expansion of the universe. Photons were once the dominant amount of energy but now pails in comparison to things like dark matter or dark energy.

Answer (score 2):

The very early universe was radiation-dominated, meaning that the gravitational effects of photons was greater than that of matter. This has been calculated and is a part of all standard cosmological models. It isn't calculated as a force, because general relativity doesn't describe gravity as a force.

Over time, both matter and radiation became diluted by cosmological expansion. The rate of dilution is faster for radiation because of the cosmological Doppler shift. Therefore there was a transition to a matter-dominated universe, and in the present era the gravitational effects of photons are negligible.